# Using get-children to list files with lastwritetime

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

With these lines of code:

```
get-childitem -Path d:\scripts –recurse | 
where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} |
Foreach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

I get a list of everything under the d:\scripts directory that is less than 1 day old in time stamp. Output:

```
D:\scripts\Data_Files
D:\scripts\Power_Shell
D:\scripts\Data_Files\BackUp_Test.txt
D:\scripts\Power_Shell\archive_test_1dayInterval.ps1
D:\scripts\Power_Shell\stop_outlook.ps1
D:\scripts\Power_Shell\test.ps1
D:\scripts\WinZip\test.wjf
```

The deal is, the file folders (Data_Files & Power_Shell) have a last write with in the date param. I just want the files as in lines 3 - 7 in output.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

```
get-childitem -Path d:\scripts –recurse |  
    where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} | 
    where-object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} |
    Foreach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

`$_.PSIsContainer` is true for folders, allowing the extra where-object filters them out.

Comment: where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1) -and -not $_.PSIsContainer} ## Don't double up where-object if you don't need to :)

Comment: used your logic to make a recursive pattern for compression and removal

Answer (score 2):

```
gci d:\scripts –recurse | 
  ? { $_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive } |
  ? { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | 
  foreach { $_.FullName }
```

or

```
gci d:\scripts –recurse | 
  ? { -not ($_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory) } |
  ? { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | 
  foreach { $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dir d:\scripts –recurse | where {!$_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} | foreach { $_.FullName }
```

Comment: hehe, markdown strikes again! You have to mark your code so it doesn't get interpreted as markup :)

Answer (score 1):

List all files in all subdirectories and sort them by LastWriteTime (newest write at the end):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object LastWriteTime,FullName
```